# Play 2.0, streaming template result?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

When using templates to produce the response, the template is computed then the result is sent.

Would it be possible to stream the result of the template while constructing the response ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streaming works by sending the result part by part, so your template should only build a part of the response.

I assume that you have an `Enumerator[Part]` where `Part` is a type modeling a result part. You can build this enumerator from a Web Service call or a database query, for example.

Then you need to transform these responses parts into html parts. You can do that using an `Enumeratee[Part, Html]`.

Finally, use the `feed` method of your HTTP result and pass it your enumerator combined with your enumeratee.

Here is an (untested) example, illustrating the above explanations:

```scala
def stream = Action { implicit request =>
  val stream: Enumerator[Part] = …
  val toHtml = Enumeratee.map[Part] { part =>
    views.html.part(part)
  }
  Ok.feed(stream &> toHtml)
}
```

Comment: OK. So to send chunks of response I have to split my template into chunks of template. My question was more about improvement of the framework. Would it be possible to have views.html... objects have an apply method which return this "feed" ? The template parsing would be done by chunks but it is the template engine which would deal with that

Comment: How would you call this template?

Comment: As I call it now: OK(views.html.mytemplate(params)). The conceptual point here is to deal with the chunks of produced HTML in the template itself. As you can have it with php (flush/ob_...) or rails (plugin template_streaming with flush/push). Having to split your template in multi templates is a huge work, dealing with @flush() in the template would be more practical.

Comment: It is technically possible, but it is not worth it since it seems you'll pay the price in the chunking plumbing.